# pandas datetime dd.mm.yyyy conversion fails

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I wish to convert a string in pandas to datetime, but conversion fails.

My data has the format for example 06.12.2015
This means day.month.year

```
try:
    #Code that may raise an error
    df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d%m%Y')
    #Raising your own errors
    raise Exception("Error converting date")
except Exception as e: 
    #code to run if error occurs
    logging.error("Exception occurred  " + filename , exc_info=True)
    #code to run if error is raised
    print("Conversion not work.")
else:
    df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%y')
```

then

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

gives object and exception is raised.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: you can replace the `.` with `''` : `pd.to_datetime(s.str.replace('.',''), format='%d%m%Y')` , tested with `s = pd.Series(['06.12.2015','06122015'])` then  `pd.to_datetime(s.str.replace('.',''), format='%d%m%Y')`

Comment: I am not having a series but a table column with date that just has the format 11.02.1984 , how would the solution look like

Comment: a table column? isnt that a series? replace `s` with `table['column']`

Comment: `df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%d.%m.%Y')` !!!

Comment: Are you able to create a "reprex"? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: **Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].** Be careful about using `except Exception` like that, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except.

Answer (score 0):

Given yourfile.dat:

```
string,date,number
a string,06.12.2015,1.0
a string,06.12.2015,2.0
```

read in:

```
b=pd.read_csv('yourfile.dat')
```

You need to put `.`s in the date format, and you need a capital `Y` to read in a four digit year.:

```
b['date']=pd.to_datetime(b['date'],format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

Comment: df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d.%m.%Y') where exactly is the difference? I already read the csv before. The input data has the format 01.12.1984

Comment: both does not work! this is not the problem, as you can see above its exactly what I did. I tried both and the data matches.

Comment: @Smiley It's hard to tell exactly what you did from just the question. A simplifed example and the full error trace might help... "I tried both and the data matches" I'm afraid I'm not sure what you are referring to here...